# Webstorm 11 - no autocompletion on es6 import statements vs node require

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to get auto completion using es6 imports for nodejs modules in webstorm?
I see all these projects converting to es6 but I wouldn't be sure why if it needs to be transpiled anyway and you lose autocompletion on non es6 sources...

I've ran into [this](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/465869;jsessionid=CE3A05054FE18FFCE741C0E579A00CB9) thread which seemed to be one of the only other people I've been able to find having the same issue but for webstorm 10...

Possibly related:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15372

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15384

Ended up opening an issue hopefully I can get an answer from the devs on whether this is intended or...
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18989

### import with "only type base completion" enabled (useless)

[image: import with "only type base completion" enabled]

### require with "only type base completion" enabled (helpful)

[image: require with "only type base completion" enabled]

### import with with "only type base completion" disabled ("several definitions" ... useless)

[image: import with with "only type base completion" disabled]

### goto declaration -> gulp file (not working, obviously)

only works for `import` if you select the `from 'gulp'` part of your import statement first, otherwise it has no clue what you want

[image: goto declaration -> gulp file (both require and import)]

[screenshot album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZgLS.jpg)

Comment: ES5 require('../../directory/module') statements also do not autocomplete for me in Webstorm 11, as they did in #10

Comment: It is good at relative imports, but I have not been able to make ones starting with a package name work.  I would hope that i would scan all the package.json's and make it so the name found there would jump to the folder its found in when used as the beginning of an import string.